# data entered to database adds back slashes

Tags: php, mysql

on my page when i enter data to the server it automatically adds back slashes before ' and " . 
i guess its because of the mysql_real_escape_string, for some reason it adds the backstrings only on my remote server while on localhost it does not add them.
the main problem is that i display the entered values later and it couses two problem:
1. the backslashes make the text unreadable and not comfortable for the eyes.
2. it deletes part of the data since its restricted to 140 characters.
what can i do to prevent them? 
my code:

```
$city = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
//here preaty regular insert query.
```

after the query the data entered in inserted with back slashes to the database. 
then on another page:

```
//get data from DB
echo $city;
```

strip slashes like this:

```
echo stripslashes($city);
```

won't help since it doesnt solve problem #2
any help and ideas will be appritiated.

EDIT: if i have the mode of magic_quotes as described below, does it mean that i dont have to use mysql_real_escape_string?

Comment: check for magic_quotes http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: ok it might be, the problem is that i dont have access to the configuration file on the server my site is hosted on. if i will manually delete the backslashes from the query is there still might be problems with the escape_string?

Comment: is the data inserted into the database with backslashes?

Comment: nope. i guess it does cancel the whole purpose of escape_string

Comment: the data *should not* have backslashes in the database

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 if i have magic_quotes as described does it mean that i dont have to use mysql_real_escape_string?

Comment: look at the answers here.. turn it off or run a function to remove the slashes, then use mysql_real_escape_string

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are escaping the variable, inserting it into the database, and then displaying the ***escaped*** variable.

A better solution would be..

```
$city = $_POST['city'];

$query = "INSERT INTO table SET city = '".mysql_real_escape_string($city)."'";

echo htmlspecialchars($city,ENT_QUOTES);
```

***NOTE***

mysql functions are deprecated

Comment: thank you for your answer, unfortanatly it doesnt work for me. i still get those "magic slashes", right now i increased the size of my variables and removes them manually... but its not optimal

Comment: I think i misunderstood your question the first time

Answer (score 1):

If you can't edit your `php.ini` file to disable magic quotes, try something like this...

```
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array)
    {
        foreach($array as &$value)
        {
            if(is_array($value))
            {
                undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value);
            }
            else
            {
                $value = stripslashes($value);
            }
        }
    }

    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST);
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET);
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE);
}
```

I'd run this before escaping variables, but keep in mind the character limit is likely still going to increase once you escape variables (via `mysql_real_escape_string()`). To help solve this, you could put a character limit on the user's input but make your back-end limit slightly higher (like 160-170) to account for the inserted characters?

Hope that helps!